Implicit Runge Kutta for system of ODEs
I am trying to build a module that solves a system of ODEs using the implicit Runge-Kutta method but it seems that I have an issue with the convergence condition. Where might the problem be? This is what I have for now:
IRK3[f_, y0_, a_, h_, b_, x_, y_] := 
Module[{result, yp, xp, n, A, bVec, k1, k2, k3, tol, maxIter}, 
result = {Join[{a}, y0]};
yp = y0;
xp = a;
n = Abs[(b - a)/h];
tol = 1*^-8;
maxIter = 100;
A = ( {
  {5/36, 2/9 - 1/15*Sqrt[15], 5/36 - 1/30*Sqrt[15]},
  {5/36 + 1/24*Sqrt[15], 2/9, 5/36 - 1/24*Sqrt[15]},
  {5/36 + 1/30 Sqrt[15], 2/9 + 1/15*Sqrt[15], 5/36}
 } );
bVec = {5/18, 4/9, 5/18};
For[i = 0, i < n + 1, i++, iter = 0;
converged = False;
k1 = ConstantArray[0, Length[y]];
k2 = ConstantArray[0, Length[y]];
k3 = ConstantArray[0, Length[y]];
While[! converged && iter < maxIter, iter++;
 k1 = f /. {x -> xp + h (1/2 - 1/10*Sqrt[15])} /. 
   Table[y[[
      n]] -> (yp[[n]] + A[[1, 1]]*k1[[n]]*h + A[[1, 2]]*k2[[n]]*h +
        A[[1, 3]]*k3[[n]]*h), {n, Length[y]}];
 k2 = f /. {x -> xp + h 1/2} /. 
   Table[y[[
      n]] -> (yp[[n]] + A[[2, 1]]*k1[[n]]*h + A[[2, 2]]*k2[[n]]*h +
        A[[2, 3]]*k3[[n]]*h), {n, Length[y]}];
 k3 = f /. {x -> xp + h (1/2 + 1/10*Sqrt[15])} /. 
   Table[y[[
      n]] -> (yp[[n]] + A[[3, 1]]*k1[[n]]*h + A[[3, 2]]*k2[[n]]*h +
        A[[3, 3]]*k3[[n]]*h), {n, Length[y]}];
 If[Norm[k1 - k2] < tol && Norm[k1 - k3] < tol, converged = True];];
yp = yp + h (bVec . {k1, k2, k3});
xp += h;
result = Join[result, {Join[{xp}, yp]}];];
Return[result];]

U = {x^2 + y2 + 1, Sin[x^2] + y3 + 2, x + y2 + 3};
list0 = IRK3[U, {0, 0, 0}, 0, 0.1, 10, x, {y1, y2, y3}];(*this is the system I tested*)

I need this in order to solve this system. The "y0_" is a list of the initial conditions. In "f_" I declare the functions in a list as well.



What ODE system are you solving? Can you show us the system in traditional math notation? 2. Which implicit Runge-Kutta scheme are you implementing? 3. Why not directly use NDSolve?


As to some of @xzczd's questions: the scheme is the same as Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "Coefficients" -> "ImplicitRungeKuttaGaussCoefficients", "DifferenceOrder" -> 5} and we're solving $y'=f$, where $f$ is an expression depending on $x$ and a discretized vector $y$; $f$ and $y$ are not shown or are variables. In addition, implicit methods define equations that need to be solved for the "slopes" $k_j$. I see no equations nor a call to a solver (like FindRoot[]), so that seems a big problem. Second, y[[n]] ->... looks wrong, but it's hard to say more without knowing what y is.

Shared some details. Apologies for being unclear. Also I have been restricted not to use any bult in methods.

So IRK3[..] computes a single step? And the While[] loop is an iterative solver?

If y[[n]] a number, then y[[n]] -> ... almost certainly won't work right. -- Have you thought of storing the values of $k_j$ for each step and inspecting them afterwards? See if they seem reasonable.

In addition to Michael E2's comment: 1. How do you use this IRK3 function? 2. Have you tested the function with a simple enough system as a first step?

This 1D test seems to work: U = {y1}; list0 = IRK3[U, {1}, 0, 1./64, 1, x, {y1}]; Exp[list0[[All, 1]]] - list0[[All, 2]]

And this 2D example seems to work: U = {-y2, y1}; list0 = IRK3[U, {1, 0}, 0, Pi/32., Pi, x, {y1, y2}]; Cos[list0[[All, 1]]] - list0[[All, 2]] // Print; Sin[list0[[All, 1]]] - list0[[All, 3]] // Print;

There are waves of questions every year asking about building own RK solver. It seems it is just a popular homework question.

Your solution agrees with NDSolve[]. I don't see a problem.

Pro tip: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica
